# mysql does not start: error 13 on bin file (permissions are set correctly)

Tags: mysql, linux, mysql-5.6

I just renamed the hostname and rebooted the server and now mysql 5.6 wont start.
(debian 7 + dotdeb)

```
150312 20:40:15 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql.mnt
2015-03-12 20:40:15 13855 [Warning] Buffered warning: Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)

2015-03-12 20:40:15 13855 [Warning] Buffered warning: Changed limits: table_cache: 431 (requested 2000)

^G/usr/sbin/mysqld: File '/var/export/websrvDB.log/websrvDB-bin.index' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2015-03-12 20:40:15 13855 [ERROR] Aborting

2015-03-12 20:40:15 13855 [Note] Binlog end
2015-03-12 20:40:15 13855 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

but it doesn't make sense

/var/export/websrvDB.log has mysql:mysql 700 and all files in there have 600 and mysql:mysql

all other ownerships also look fine and the server starts when I turn of the binlog.

there are 134files in the log folder with quite some GB. the .index files seems to have all of them correctly included. I am also puzzled by the ^G in the logfile, it appears every time.

Can anyone please help, thank you.

---

cd /var/export/websrvDB.log ; ls -l

```
total 134170264
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql        143 Feb 23 19:45 websrvDB-bin.000001
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql      12634 Feb 24 18:21 websrvDB-bin.000002
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1087177258 Feb 24 20:23 websrvDB-bin.000003
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1121509434 Feb 24 22:44 websrvDB-bin.000004
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1186530117 Feb 25 00:18 websrvDB-bin.000005
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1091943807 Feb 25 01:38 websrvDB-bin.000006
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1082287219 Feb 25 03:17 websrvDB-bin.000007
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1098320416 Feb 25 05:00 websrvDB-bin.000008
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1081566516 Feb 25 06:42 websrvDB-bin.000009
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1076875987 Feb 25 08:25 websrvDB-bin.000010
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1095260241 Feb 25 10:11 websrvDB-bin.000011
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1115154789 Feb 25 11:49 websrvDB-bin.000012
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1160372496 Feb 25 13:42 websrvDB-bin.000013
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1154960867 Feb 26 18:37 websrvDB-bin.000014
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1179407616 Feb 26 20:23 websrvDB-bin.000015
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1076835188 Feb 26 21:58 websrvDB-bin.000016
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1119616839 Feb 26 23:37 websrvDB-bin.000017
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1090227407 Feb 27 01:06 websrvDB-bin.000018
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1175220171 Feb 27 02:49 websrvDB-bin.000019
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1127677063 Feb 27 04:19 websrvDB-bin.000020
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1098126690 Feb 27 05:55 websrvDB-bin.000021
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1134191605 Feb 27 07:25 websrvDB-bin.000022
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1122427455 Feb 27 09:09 websrvDB-bin.000023
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1135147659 Feb 27 10:45 websrvDB-bin.000024
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1125946921 Feb 27 12:31 websrvDB-bin.000025
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1092043180 Feb 27 14:19 websrvDB-bin.000026
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1075775510 Feb 27 15:58 websrvDB-bin.000027
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1128520626 Feb 27 17:47 websrvDB-bin.000028
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1091159443 Feb 27 19:22 websrvDB-bin.000029
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1112875335 Feb 27 20:53 websrvDB-bin.000030
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1082121151 Feb 27 22:23 websrvDB-bin.000031
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1152197988 Feb 28 00:04 websrvDB-bin.000032
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1129642072 Feb 28 01:35 websrvDB-bin.000033
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1109195165 Feb 28 03:14 websrvDB-bin.000034
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1159186180 Feb 28 04:53 websrvDB-bin.000035
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1148540354 Feb 28 06:26 websrvDB-bin.000036
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1112285583 Feb 28 08:01 websrvDB-bin.000037
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1124405095 Feb 28 09:44 websrvDB-bin.000038
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1086068375 Feb 28 11:29 websrvDB-bin.000039
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1074889949 Feb 28 13:16 websrvDB-bin.000040
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1110640917 Feb 28 15:05 websrvDB-bin.000041
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1097061339 Feb 28 16:55 websrvDB-bin.000042
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1091835063 Feb 28 18:29 websrvDB-bin.000043
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1123465247 Feb 28 20:09 websrvDB-bin.000044
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1120903068 Feb 28 21:49 websrvDB-bin.000045
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1104045209 Feb 28 23:23 websrvDB-bin.000046
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1075161414 Mar  1 01:07 websrvDB-bin.000047
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1079931470 Mar  1 02:51 websrvDB-bin.000048
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1089022624 Mar  1 04:33 websrvDB-bin.000049
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1109861251 Mar  1 06:26 websrvDB-bin.000050
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1083623418 Mar  1 07:58 websrvDB-bin.000051
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1076549912 Mar  1 09:29 websrvDB-bin.000052
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1116605273 Mar  1 11:13 websrvDB-bin.000053
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1075945796 Mar  1 12:46 websrvDB-bin.000054
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1083113492 Mar  1 14:22 websrvDB-bin.000055
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1133158602 Mar  1 15:56 websrvDB-bin.000056
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1077916188 Mar  1 17:37 websrvDB-bin.000057
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1090615582 Mar  1 19:10 websrvDB-bin.000058
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1139990328 Mar  1 20:53 websrvDB-bin.000059
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1134876873 Mar  1 22:40 websrvDB-bin.000060
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1083456779 Mar  2 00:12 websrvDB-bin.000061
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1122142023 Mar  2 01:55 websrvDB-bin.000062
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1186471154 Mar  2 03:43 websrvDB-bin.000063
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1127402176 Mar  2 05:17 websrvDB-bin.000064
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1125413082 Mar  2 07:05 websrvDB-bin.000065
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1099621274 Mar  2 08:39 websrvDB-bin.000066
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1089318088 Mar  2 10:13 websrvDB-bin.000067
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1133336276 Mar  2 11:52 websrvDB-bin.000068
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1084554026 Mar  2 13:31 websrvDB-bin.000069
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1095748746 Mar  2 15:13 websrvDB-bin.000070
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1086093387 Mar  2 16:50 websrvDB-bin.000071
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1097876338 Mar  2 18:36 websrvDB-bin.000072
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1107253853 Mar  2 20:16 websrvDB-bin.000073
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1074499187 Mar  2 22:08 websrvDB-bin.000074
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1108353519 Mar  3 00:03 websrvDB-bin.000075
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1089224171 Mar  3 01:25 websrvDB-bin.000076
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1159334605 Mar  3 02:56 websrvDB-bin.000077
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1142869855 Mar  3 04:30 websrvDB-bin.000078
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1109087904 Mar  3 06:20 websrvDB-bin.000079
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1091382217 Mar  3 07:57 websrvDB-bin.000080
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1081426102 Mar  3 09:29 websrvDB-bin.000081
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1083136326 Mar  3 11:15 websrvDB-bin.000082
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1114845600 Mar  3 13:00 websrvDB-bin.000083
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1088647835 Mar  3 14:45 websrvDB-bin.000084
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1086713145 Mar  3 16:35 websrvDB-bin.000085
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1106967849 Mar  3 18:27 websrvDB-bin.000086
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1085522515 Mar  3 20:07 websrvDB-bin.000087
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1109263916 Mar  3 21:59 websrvDB-bin.000088
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1119403385 Mar  3 23:49 websrvDB-bin.000089
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1124332388 Mar  4 01:37 websrvDB-bin.000090
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1103510594 Mar  4 03:23 websrvDB-bin.000091
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1094601772 Mar  4 05:17 websrvDB-bin.000092
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1076745884 Mar  5 12:24 websrvDB-bin.000093
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1162650801 Mar  5 13:33 websrvDB-bin.000094
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1132094717 Mar  5 14:46 websrvDB-bin.000095
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1088579042 Mar  5 15:43 websrvDB-bin.000096
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1087194400 Mar  5 16:35 websrvDB-bin.000097
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1101657663 Mar  5 17:25 websrvDB-bin.000098
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1106463332 Mar  5 18:05 websrvDB-bin.000099
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1115337638 Mar  5 18:44 websrvDB-bin.000100
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1089658949 Mar  5 19:17 websrvDB-bin.000101
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1076160676 Mar  5 19:50 websrvDB-bin.000102
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1092955658 Mar  5 20:25 websrvDB-bin.000103
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1084219729 Mar  5 20:59 websrvDB-bin.000104
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1113240888 Mar  5 21:28 websrvDB-bin.000105
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1074056657 Mar  5 22:06 websrvDB-bin.000106
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1074775076 Mar  5 22:40 websrvDB-bin.000107
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1128158980 Mar  5 23:17 websrvDB-bin.000108
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1092187915 Mar  5 23:48 websrvDB-bin.000109
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1078401155 Mar  6 00:25 websrvDB-bin.000110
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1102177576 Mar  6 01:00 websrvDB-bin.000111
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1087022135 Mar  6 01:36 websrvDB-bin.000112
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1082729607 Mar  6 02:17 websrvDB-bin.000113
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1080814610 Mar  6 02:55 websrvDB-bin.000114
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1078733843 Mar  6 03:35 websrvDB-bin.000115
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1076538345 Mar  6 04:15 websrvDB-bin.000116
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1074724341 Mar  6 04:57 websrvDB-bin.000117
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1079546730 Mar  6 05:39 websrvDB-bin.000118
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1080282707 Mar  6 06:26 websrvDB-bin.000119
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1074087059 Mar  6 07:12 websrvDB-bin.000120
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1077486222 Mar  6 08:02 websrvDB-bin.000121
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1075726356 Mar  6 08:51 websrvDB-bin.000122
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1076102229 Mar  7 21:37 websrvDB-bin.000123
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1077231040 Mar  8 11:40 websrvDB-bin.000124
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql 1077058120 Mar  9 17:22 websrvDB-bin.000125
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql  792830910 Mar 10 17:27 websrvDB-bin.000126
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql  780084400 Mar 12 20:01 websrvDB-bin.000127
-rw------- 1 mysql mysql       6731 Mar 10 17:27 websrvDB-bin.index
```

cd /var/export; ls -l

```
drwx------ 2 mysql    mysql    12288 Mar 10 17:27 websrvDB.log
```

my.cnf

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql.mnt
tmpdir      = /tmp
tmpdir      = /var/lib/mysql.mnt/tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
#bind-address       = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
general_log             = 0
#
# Error logging goes to syslog due to /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf.
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
slow_query_log = 1
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.

server-id       = 201
log_bin         = /var/export/websrvDB.log/websrvDB-bin
binlog_format       = ROW
binlog_do_db        = websrvDB_pdw
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 1
sync_binlog         = 1
binlog_ignore_db    = websrvDB_archive
binlog_ignore_db        = websrvDB_temp
binlog_ignore_db        = websrvDB_userdata

expire_logs_days    = 5
#max_binlog_size         = 100M
#
# basic loggin
log-error       = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# It seems that we need this for successful mysql-5.1 -> mysql-5.6 upgrade
innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_file_format=Barracuda
innodb_buffer_pool_size=2GB
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem



[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Comment: Please run  `cd /var/export/websrvDB.log ; ls -l` and `cat my.cnf` and post its output.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I am not all that comfortable with the Permissions you have.

Since mysqld is not running, try the following

```
cd /var/export/websrvDB.log
mkdir junk
cd junk
mv ../websrvDB-bin.* .
cd ..
service mysql start
ls -l websrvDB-bin.*
```

mysqld should start up and create a new binary log and index file. Look at the permissions of `websrvDB-bin.000001` and `websrvDB-bin.index` and those should be the correct permissions.

You should also do this

```
chmod -R 644 /var/export/websrvDB.log
```

and try restarting MySQL

Comment: It still doesnt start, gives the same error message. the /var/export/websrvDB.log/ is a mounted folder from openVZ. For testing purposes I tried a folder with another name also, still same error.

Comment: What is the problem with the permissions, why are you uncomfortable with them? Ownership is mysql and rw(x), isn't that the way it should be?

Comment: Just not used to `600` or `700`. I usually see `660`.

Comment: changed it to 660, doesn't change anything.

Comment: Please try this: `cd /var/export/websrvDB-bin.log ; touch test.txt ; ls -l`. What do you see ???

Comment: I created a folder in /var/lib/mysql.binlog and now mysql starts with binlog on. I somehow start to think this might be a openVZ problem, the /var/lib/.. is inside the VZ, the /var/export is a share to outside. ty for you help up to now

Comment: creating the test.txt worked. i also could create the ./junk folder: 
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 12288 Mar 12 21:24 junk
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Mar 12 21:54 test.txt
(that is why I am so puzzled, everything looks like it is working)

Answer (score 1):

If your server is using Apparmor, you need make sure apparmor is letting MySQL write to the new location.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is going on on this server, but the problem was related to openVZ.

For whatever reason the server decided he does not want to put the binlog on a folder which has been mounted. Still trying to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was SELinux. I figured this out by getting "denied" in the output:

grep -ar mysqld /var/log/audit/* | grep denied

Next, I disabled SELinux according to this article:
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-disable-selinux-on-centos-8/

and mysql started without problems (in my case it was a test VM, not sure if this is the right solution for production environments).

Answer (score -1):

SELINUX might be the cause of your grief. Review my blogpost for more details on how to fix: https://sysengineers.wordpress.com/2021/03/22/mysqld-fails-to-start-after-moving-its-data-directory/